# How to restrict a spatial search by a field value

Tags: solr

I have spatial search working well with SOLR 3.2

Example :

```
    ?q=*&fq={!geofilt pt=48.86761919303129,2.3527903735351856 sfield=coordinates d=5}
```

I cant find the query to filter by a specific document field value.

same code above  with  type="activity" by example

Is it possible ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional fq to your query -- &fq=type:activity

Comment: i thought  this way it override the fq params, but no, it's working

so, if i want all spot and activity type in spatial area i write  

   `?q=*&fq={!geofilt pt=48.86761919303129,2.3527903735351856 sfield=coordinates d=5}&fq=type:(activity OR spot)`